# FBSDKLog missing permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to share news with facebook. Here is the code:

```
RACSignal *sign = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        if([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]){
            NSLog(@"1 blck");
            NSLog(@"curr tok? %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
            [subscriber sendNext:@YES];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"2 blck");
            FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
            [login logOut];
            login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
            [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] fromViewController:APP.window.rootViewController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"log passed by");
                self.isExecuting = YES;
                if (error) {
                    NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ru.myServer.fb" code:-3 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:error.localizedDescription}];
                    [subscriber sendError:err];
                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ru.myServer.fb" code:-4 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"Недоступно"}];
                    [subscriber sendError:err];
                } else {
                    NSString *strToken = result.token.tokenString;
                    NSString *strUserId = result.token.userID;
                    NSDictionary *dctProps = @{@"token":strToken, @"user_id":strUserId};
                    [subscriber sendNext:dctProps];
                    [subscriber sendCompleted];
                }
            }];
        }
```

Its pretty straightforward, even if you not familiar with Reactive Cocoa.

For some reason, that code works (publish news) for one account, that has been authorized before, but when I try do share news for another acc, it complete block but send error

> FBSDKLog: Warning: Access token is missing publish_actions permissions

. Obviously, there is no news shared.

Why is that happen?

Answer (score 2):

To allow publishing inside your app with the FBSDK, you have to ask at login the additional permission to the user : `publish_actions`

Example :

```
 [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                         fromViewController:self
                                    handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //TODO: process error or result.
  }];
```

Référence : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

Comment: I am very familiar with the docs, thank you. And what you said doesn’t change the fact that it is not a _reading_ permission, and as such it should be asked for differently - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions#permissions-login Plus, [best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices) as summed up by FB say not to let ask apps for permissions such as publish_actions on initial user login, but only when the permission is actually needed for the first time (i.e., user actively clicks a button that triggers a share.)

Comment: @CBroe Ok, I was wrong.. I don't know why. Will update the answer and deleted my "almost rude" comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

For all who may interested.

There is no problem in code above. Problem is, facebook need to approve and review app, before making `public_actions` availible for users, that not admins in https://developers.facebook.com.

So, you have to follow specific instructions from facebook team to make that permission scope available.